# PHP link not working - cannot find the mistake

Tags: php, html, database, content-management-system

I built a CMS system using CKEditor and KCFinder that store information od a databse via textarea/php. So far so good!

The issue comes to when I want to store and display images that link to themselves. The way I am storing images is exactly the same: There is a textarea where I insert an image via KCFinder/CKEditor. The image is uploaded to the server and the path stored at the database. Later I try to pick up that path from the database to display the image (that part also works) and because I want the image to link to itself, I try to use the same method to insert the url on the link. Problem? The link is missing.

Can anyone point me the error and suggest any solution? I would be so thankful!

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM php_maskiner ORDER BY timestamp DESC";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or print ('<div class="alert alert-standard fade in">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
        <strong>Can't read the database!</strong>
        </div>' . $sql . "<br />" . mysql_error());

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
                $entry = stripslashes($row['entry']);
                $images = html_entity_decode($row['images']);
                $img_url = $row['images'];
                $img_pack = '<div class="mask3 span3">
            <a rel="prettyPhoto" href="' . $img_url . '">' . $images . '</a>
            </div>';

?>

                <article class="span12 post"> 
                    <?php echo $img_pack; ?>
                    <div class="inside">
                      <div class="span8 entry-content">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                            <p><?php echo $entry; ?></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
    <?php
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I think that this might be a problem caused by CKEditor. In the database the image path is store as: . This is in my understanding what is being outputted. **How do I do to output only "/nysida/admin/kcfinder/upload/images/1307594_10243178.jpg"?**

Comment: How is the image's path stored?

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is still using the `mysql_` extensions to access your databases. You must use PDO (if available):

Example (for mysql):

```
try {
    $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM php_maskiner ORDER BY timestamp DESC');
    $STH->execute();

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
        $title = $row->title;
        $entry = $row->entry;
        $images = $row->images;
        $img_url = $row->images;
        $img_pack = 
            '<div class="mask3 span3">
                <a rel="prettyPhoto" href="'.$img_url.'"><img src="'.$images.'"></a>
             </div>';
    }

    $DBH = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-standard fade in">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">&times;</a>
        <strong>Can\'t read the database!</strong>
        </div><br />'.$e;
}
```

And later in your code:

```
<?php echo 
    '<article class="span12 post"> 
        '.$img_pack.'
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="span8 entry-content">
                <div class="span12">
                    <h2>'.$title.'</h2>
                    <p>'.$entry.'</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>';
?>
```

And regarding the original question: make sure `$img_url` is not `null`.

Comment: Well first off, thanks for the very complete answer. I do recognize that I need an update on my PHP knowledge. I have tried your code and it is not working better then mine. The links are also not working and the images are now not displaying. This is the outputted code:  `<a src="/nysida/admin/kcfinder/upload/images/332805_3333.jpg" "="" href="<img alt=" rel="prettyPhoto">

    ">

    <img "="" src="<img alt="></img>

    ">

</a>`. Now, regarding to your answer to the original question, I don't understand. If `$img_url = $row['images'];` how can it be null?

Comment: Here is the error message I receive when I click on the image: "Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist."